# Ruby date comparison not working?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to determine if something happened in the past week. I'm gettign the begining of the week with `Time.now.last_week.sunday` and trying to compare with the `>` operator.

```
sunday = Time.now.last_week.sunday
puts "Last Sunday:  " + sunday.to_s
json = json["objects"]
puts "JSON objects found: " + json.count.to_s
puts "checking date"
json.select! do |statement|
  puts "\tObject date: " + Date.parse(statement["statement_date"]).to_s
  puts "\tSince Sunday? " + (Date.parse(statement["statement_date"]) > sunday).to_s
  (Date.parse(statement["statement_date"]) > sunday)
end
```

The problem I run into is that things happening the day after, are still filtered out:

```
Last Sunday:  2017-02-05 23:59:59 -0500
JSON objects found: 10
checking date
    Object date: 2017-02-06
    Since Sunday? false
    Object date: 2017-02-02
    Since Sunday? false
    Object date: 2017-02-06
    Since Sunday? false
    Object date: 2017-02-05
    Since Sunday? false
    Object date: 2017-02-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sunday` is `Time` class not `Date`. Try to parse it into date like this.

```
sunday = Time.now.last_week.sunday.to_date
```